# SQL Server JOIN Database like wordpress

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to make generic database. It should looks like below example.

http://s11.postimage.org/4n6sigf37/Untitled_picture.png

I need some dynamic store procedure or query.

It's kind of wordpress post storing in my sql.

I need to do with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to do a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?ppud=4) of the data where you take the values in the `key` column and transform each of those into its own column.  If you know the values that you want to transform, then you can hard-code them via a static `PIVOT`, similar to this:

```
select id, name, email, password, state, city
from 
(
  select u.id,
    u.name,
    u.email,
    u.password,
    m.[key],
    m.value
  from users u
  left join usermeta m
    on u.id = m.user_id
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for [key] in ([State], [City])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7dbd/3)

But you stated that you have an unknown number of columns, so you will want to use a dynamic `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([key]) 
                    from usermeta
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, name, email, password, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select u.id,
                  u.name,
                  u.email,
                  u.password,
                  m.[key],
                  m.value
                from users u
                left join usermeta m
                  on u.id = m.user_id
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for [key] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7dbd/4)

Comment: @keyurajmera then you can throw this into a stored procedure where you pass in the variable of `@type` to filter the fields for the `PIVOT`

Comment: Hi bluefeet can I have your email id? I have another question after this one. How can I create view with unknown number of columns. Actually I wanna create some view or function so i can do more query on it. like with that view pagination.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.Email, a.Password
    (SELECT Value FROM UserMeta WHERE Key = 'State' AND User_Id = a.ID) AS State,
    (SELECT Value FROM UserMeta WHERE Key = 'City' AND User_Id = a.ID) AS City
FROM User a
```

Comment: I need some dynamic ways. may be columns are more that twos in seconds table.

Comment: @keyurajmera You need to give more information with regards to your requirements.

Comment: Hi, Can I get through some joins or something else. I have change my image. Thank you for helping me.